# Awk append existing CSV column of variable number

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I know how to pass variables to awk, but I haven't been able to combine that with the column number functionality when working with a CSV. I'm also not sure how to perform a string concatenation this way.

I'm expecting some columns in my CSVs to contain dates in `MM-dd-yyyy` or `yyyy/MM/dd` format, or some permutation of those, and would like to append a default `hh:mm:ss` onto it, so a column of `1/10/2017` becomes `1/10/2017 00:00:00`. I've tried doing something along these lines in awk, but it doesn't seem to recognize the column I'm trying to reference. And I don't think this is how string concatenation is done.

```
for file in *.csv; do
  headline=$(head -n 1 $file)
  byline=$(sed '2q;d' $file)
  IFS=', ' read -r -a headers <<< $headline  
  IFS=', ' read -r -a entries <<< $byline

  for i in "${!headers[@]}"; do                                 
    date='^[0-9]+[/-][0-9]+[/-][0-9]+$'

    if [[ ${entries[$i]} =~ $date ]] ; then                 
      awk -F, -v col='$i' '{$($col)+="00:00:00";}1' OFS=, $file  
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Sorry to break this to you, but you actually don't know how to pass shell variables to awk: using single quotes will prevent the variable substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer your question if you provided a minimal reproducible example of your input data.

Without knowing the data, I assume that you should get what you're looking by replacing your awk command with the following:

```
awk -v col=$(($i + 1)) 'BEGIN{FS=", "} {print $col " 00:00:00"}' "$file"
```